# Select spinner without triggering listener

Tags: android, android-spinner

**Long version** I have two spinners on my screen and when I select the one, I do certain operations, and the other spinner should display the original selection, because of design patterns. In this situation, I let the user select the elements on a list  by year, and by state. You would agree with me that when the user choose to select by year, the spinner regarding the state should display the default selection (the one that displays all of the item) and not the last selected one.

I am trying to do this from this morning, but when I found this solution I really though I was done.

**Short version** I want to setSelection(0) on the spinner which is not clicked, without triggering its listener (which by the way, will setSelection(0) on the first spinner, if triggered)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    // irrelevant code...

    mYearSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onYearSelected);
    mStateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onStateSelected);

    // irrelevant code...
}

private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onYearSelected = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mStateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
        mStateSpinner.setSelection(0);
        mStateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onStateSelected);

        // Do something...
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }
};

private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onStateSelected = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mYearSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
        mYearSpinner.setSelection(0);
        mYearSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onYearSelected);

        // Do something...
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }
};
```

But no! The listeners will just fire, indiscriminately.

Is there someone who knows how to handle this problem?
Why this solution wouldn't work?

---

As requested, here is the full code of my `onCreateView(...)` method

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_career, container, false);

    mExamListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.exam_list_view);
    mYearSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.select_by_year_spinner);
    mStateSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.select_by_state_spinner);
    mLoadingView = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_career_loading_spinner);

    mExamListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Exam exam = (Exam) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (exam.isBookable()) {
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                SessionsDialogFragment.newInstance(exam).show(fm, null);
            }
        }
    });

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> yearAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.spinner_year, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    yearAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> stateAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.spinner_state, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    stateAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    mYearSpinner.setAdapter(yearAdapter);
    mStateSpinner.setAdapter(stateAdapter);

    mYearSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onYearSelected);
    mStateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onStateSelected);

    return view;
}
```

---

I tried implementing what --- suggested and I want to report here what happens.

When the application starts all the two listeners are executed only once.
Then, if I select an item on the first spinner (let's say the year spinner), the expected listener is executed only once (as it should be), and so it is, if I keep selecting items on it.
Ultimately, if I select and item on the state spinner, the listeners are executed in this way

```
1. onStateListener
2. onYearListener
3. onStateListener
```

Comment: show the full code of `onCreateView`

Comment: @Raghunandan question updated

Comment: I have no clue what your problem is. Can you explain what you want and what does not happen? You want one of the spinner's listener to fire when the other one finishes, or what exactly?

Comment: @YordanLyubenov sure... I want to setSelection(0) on the spinner which is not clicked, without triggering its listener (which by the way, will setSelection(0) on the first spinner, if triggered)

Comment: So you want to enable the first spinner after the second? If you want to have only setSelection, just add that in the listener you want that to happen. You don't need to specify a whole listener when you do not need one. Specify it when you DO need it. Still, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, I need the listener to perform a filtering on a list. But if the filtering happens when an item on the first spinner is selected, I want the second to return to its initial state (that's why I setSelection(0) on it)

Comment: Swap the setSelection(0). If you want the first to be refreshed, it has to be done in the OTHER one. Currently, when you select the year one, you are refreshing THAT one.

Comment: I don't understand. In the yearSelector, I am doing `mStateSpinner.setSelection(0);`, so I'm refreshing the other one. Otherwise it would have been `mYearSpinner.setSelection(0);`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Okay, I didn't read it well enough (kinda busy). So either try what @Dreagen suggested, or just debug some more without those setOnItemSelectedListener. I suspect the setting to null might disrupt something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading your comments it sounds like you want to set the selection of a second spinner to 0 from your first spinners `onItemClick` method without triggering its listener.

If you keep a record of the old position the spinners are at in integer variables we can check if the position has changed and only run the code if it has.

That way if we set the old position variable to 0 before changing the spinners current position to 0 it will think its position hasn't changed and so won't run the code in the listener.

```
private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onYearSelected = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (lastYearPosition != position) {
        //Do you code here
        lastStatePosition = 0;
        mStateSpinner.setSelection(0);
    }
    lastYearPosition = position;
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }
};

private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onStateSelected = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (lastStatePosition != position) {
        //Do your code here
        lastYearPosition = 0;
        mYearSpinner.setSelection(0);
    }
    lastStatePosition = position;
}
```

Comment: tried that and it didn't work. Took the time to try it again, but nothing. Also, I tried performing the tasks out of the `if` and inside the `if`, but nothing. EDIT: When I say it didn't work, I mean the listeners are executed no matter what. This is becoming so strange, I'm beginning suspect it's a bug with the platform..

Comment: So the problem is that when you select an item from one spinner, it runs the onItemSelected code from both of them?

Comment: The selection of the two spinners is set to 0, and the two listeners are called.

Comment: I have edited my answer, I think it was just that the boolean was getting changed to true before the code in the other listener was being ran. Try it now

Comment: I updated my question reporting what happens exactly when I click on the items of the two spinner. EDIT: Just noticed your new answer. I'll report back soon

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. If I select the first spinner at the beginning and keep selecting different items on it, the listener will be called only the first time of two. ie 1st time, 3rd time, 5th time... and so on

Comment: Even if I select always from two different spinners the listeners aren't properly called at the beginning (after the first two, it's all right...)

Comment: I just want to +1 you for the support though :)

Comment: Cheers for +1, still thinking about another solution

Comment: It does indeed! Thank you for that. Please update even the description of your answer (it still talks about a boolean). Also, it would be awesome if you would describe a little bit the process as I can't see the whole picture of how this is working. Thank you. =)

Comment: Happy to have helped!